# UITableHeaderFooterView from xib key-value-coding crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I'm making a table header from a XIB however i keep getting a crash for key-value-coding compliance on my labels in the header on this line ..

```
UIView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"MileageEntryTableHeaderView"];
```

In my viewDidLoad I call

```
[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MileageEntryTableHeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"MileageEntryTableHeaderView"];
```

then in my  `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate i have

```
UIView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"MileageEntryTableHeaderView"];
return headerView;
```

My labels in the xib are just standard labels. I allocate them in my .h and connected them in my xib from the file's owner.  (right click files owner, drag to appropriate label).  What exactly is causing my crash here?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get this crash if you have previously created a connection between the xib and your code and then renamed the property in your code, or delete it and create a new connection.
XCode doesn't tidy up deleted connections or renamed connections. Check exactly what connections there are in in interface builder (use the connections inspector), you probably have an out dated one.

Comment: I checked and all of the connections are in the connection manager.  I added them again just in case, but still crashes.  However, removing them did not cause a crash.  Although i have no references to my labels now.

Comment: ok, i found the problem.  I had to connect from the view to the labels.  Creating connections from file's owner to the labels caused a crash.

Comment: @JMD can you explain what and how exactly you overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For anybody else having the similar troubles:

I also had a crash when calling `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier`.

In the end, the issue was that I was loading a UIView from the NIB where iOS was expecting a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. To fix, I had to make sure that the UIView in the NIB was set to a custom class of type `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` (or a subclass of it) in the Identity inspector.